# Connection of TRRS microphone not TRRS headset

Tags: audio, microphone, input, trs, trrs

I know for headset

T- Left

R- Right

R- mic

S- Ground

But for only microphone

T - unknown ?

R - unknown ?

R - mic

S - Ground

What are those unknown?

I want to plug it to my computer which has separate port for headset and mic.
I already have bluetooth headset. Thinking of buying mic. But most of them only have TRRS plug.

So I am trying to understand TRRS connection of microphone.

Comment: Check if the computer port will accept TRS (mic only) or TRRS as input. If it is mic only, you have to buy a TRRS to TRS splitter/adapter.  If the port is capable of accessing TRRS, then your pc should have the correct driver software to take mic input alone from the TRRS port.

Comment: I tired TRRS headphone in TRS microphone port. The mic doesn't work as we know that for TRS mic Tip - mic, R-mic, S-mic and TRRS headphone has (third R) R- mic. But if TRRS mic has similar connection then It would work. That's what I trying to ask. What are T and R connection for TRRS microphone?

Comment: So basically what I am wondering is, in my computer's TRS mic port, TRRS headset's mic doesn't work but, when we talk about solo TRRS microphone (no headset) then, it might work.